# R - adding a variable from another dataset with different # rows

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I'm currently working on R on a survey on schools and I would like to add a variable with the population of the city the school is in.

In the first data set I have all the survey respondants which includes a variable "city_name". I have managed to find online a list of the cities with their population which I have imported on R.

What I now would like to do is to add a variable in dataset_1 called city_pop which is equal to the city population when city_name is in both data sets. It might be relevant to know that the first dataset has around 1200 rows while the second one has around 36000 rows.

I've tried several things including the following:

```
data_set_1$Pop_city = ifelse(data_set_1$city_name == data_set_2$city_name, data_set_2$Pop_city, 0)
```

Any clues?

Thanks!!

Comment: can you add a `dput()` of your data? on this occasion, we can think about a potential solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *merge* the two dataset:

```
new_df <- merge(data_set_1, data_set_2, by="city_name")
```

The result will be a dataframe containing only matching rows (in your case, 1200 rows assuming that all cities in data_set_1 are also in data_set_2) and all columns of both data frames. If you want to also keep non-matching rows of data_set_1, you can use the `all.x` option:

```
new_df <- merge(data_set_1, data_set_2, by="city_name", all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that but the city names where in lower case in one dataset and in upper case in the other so It didnt work. You gave me a second wind

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you could try using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data_set_1 %>% 
  mutate(Pop_city = ifelse(city_name %in% data_set_2$city_name, 
                           data_set_2$Pop_city[city_name == data_set_2$city_name],
                           0))
```

or using a `left_join`

```
data_set_1 %>% 
  left_join(data_set_2, by = "city_name")
```

perhaps followed by a `select(names(data_set_1), Pop_city)`.